# Laravel : Delete all records that are not in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a datepicker calendar in my views, and basically I need to synchronize the selected dates (that I send in ajax) with a BoxDeliveryDate model (which only has one column named "date").

So in my Controller I was able to write a pretty nice method to only create a new record if one the selected dates is not yet stored in the database, like this :

```
foreach (Request::get('dates') as $date) {
        $date_formated = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
        BoxDeliveryDate::firstOrCreate(['date'=>$date_formated]);
    }
```

Now, if the user de-select one the dates in the datepicker, later, and synchronize, I need to delete it from the database.

Is there a nice way to do that in Laravel ? In other words, to delete every record of the table that are NOT in my `Request::get('dates')` ?

Also, I searched for a simple way to synchronize everything with only one method, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Consider using Carbon for dates and times, it saves a load of headaches!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `whereNotIn()` for that:

```
BoxDeliveryDate::whereNotIn('date', Request::get('dates'))->delete();
```

Note that this will not trigger any model events nor will it work with soft delete. Also, depending on the format of `dates` you might have to format the array before passing it to `whereNotIn()`.

Also I believe it should be `Request::input('dates')` but it's possible that both actually works...

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the soft delete trait (built into Laravel) if your doing mass deletes!

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: Why? Actually soft deletes make mass deleting more difficult because you have to either loop over the collection and delete the models one by one or you have to write do an update statement with the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

$this->model->whereNotIn('id', $ids)->delete();